# Geospatial clustering (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, cluster-analysis, markerclusterer

I have hundreds of thousands objects on map. And select from base almost all of them (within map container rectangle on a small scale) is very bad practice. Need clustering inside DB.
In a relational database is often used additional table - cluster, which is selected first.
Is there some best practice for geospatial clustering inside MongoDB? Google says nothing.

UPD. Wanted like this, but in MongoDB: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis

Answer (score 8):

For hundreds of thousands of items, the built-in [MongoDB geospatial indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) works pretty well depending on what you're doing.

The Mongo ["Haystack Queries"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#geospatial-indexes-haystack-index) may also be along the lines of what you're thinking.

You might also be interested in this [discussion of Mongo's GIS capabilities compared to an RMDBS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/how-to-store-lines-and-polygons-in-json-documents/12728#12728)

Comment: Yes, but just geospatial indexing don't solve how to select cluster but not thousands of object in it. Ie Mongo does not offer a solution out of the box

Comment: Correct. It wouldn't be too hard implement "kmeans" clustering using MongoDB.  Doable but definitely not out of the box.  A sketch using MapReduce is here: http://blog.data-miners.com/2008/02/mapreduce-and-k-means-clustering.html

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?